# Unable to install checkpoint in R

Tags: r, r-package, checkpoint

I needed help to install `checkpoint` package. I did conda clean all and conda update all to no good.

As per screenshot links below, only some packages did not get installed while doing `install.packages("checkpoint")` on R console. I retried using different mirrors for download to no good.

So, I am not able to install shiny as well since it depends on the `checkpoint` package.

STEP 2-

I also tried by downloading the checkpoint package as an archive (zip) from [CRAN](https://cran-r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/index.html) i.e. (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/checkpoint_1.0.2.zip). I unzipped the folder but next, which file from inside should i run to install checkpoint to my RStudio in my Windows.

I am novice to R programming, so please help.

Screenshot links-
Top of screenshot - https://ibb.co/841Nzph;
Bottom of screenshot - https://ibb.co/Z1CGtSR

Best

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code--just post it as nicely formatted text.

Comment: There's a general FAQ for package installation difficulties--trying the solutions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25721890/903061) would be a very good first step.

Comment: From your screenshots, I can't see the command you ran, but it looks like it mentions "trying URL..." which means you were installing from the internet, not from a zip file you downloaded. Checking the [CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/index.html) we can also see that `checkpoint` depends on several packages (jsonlite, yaml, withr, pkgdepends) which may also have their own dependencies. So unless you have previously installed those packages, installing from a Zip will not work.

Comment: Try to specify the ```type``` of the the package you're installing: ```install.packages("checkpoint", type = "source")```.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas - I tried installing other packages as suggested on top left half of the RStudio IDE beside ui.R as well as the ones in the CRAN page [seeing some version issues though - have to verify those]. However it still asks for checkpoint as of now. I am more interested in knowing how to run the archive mentioned against Windows Binaries (r-release and r-devel) on the Downloads section of the CRAN page.

Comment: I managed to install after some efforts.